# Preparing two raster datasets for grouped barplot

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, dem

I have two overlying raster datasets in ArcGIS which do have the same extent. One is a digital elevation model and the other one is a raster mask that contains three landuse classes (see figure below).

[image]

Is there a way I can concatenate the value from the mask class to each pixel of the digital elevation model?

I am trying to prepare the data for a hypsography barplot of area per elevation bin of 100m. For each elevation bin of 100m, I would like to plot the percentage of area for each class, analogous to the figure below.

[image]

Ideally would be an ASCII or .txt format to export the table into better suited software for this purpose such as R or matlab.

The structure in the attribute table for each overlapping pixel should look something like this.

Is it possible to join raster table information together so that I can get a table such as this?

```
 ElevationValueDEM (Raster1) MaskValue(Raster2)
 224                         Grass
 378                         Forest
  .                            .
  .                            .
  .                            .
  .                            .
```

With this structure it would be easy to group the classes together and do a grouped barplot.

Comment: Trivial in R - its something like `data.frame(elevation = raster1[], mask=raster2[])`, if both rasters have same extent *and* resolution...

Comment: Are you needing to work in a Raster format? If you convert both to shapefiles and run the intersect and dissolve tools you will get a breakdown of elevations and land use type. This attribute table can be exported out to txt for editing.